# Django: How to access form field input_type in a template

Tags: django-forms

I am rendering a form this way:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div>
        {{ field.errors }}
        <input  name="{{field.name}}" type="{{field.widget.input_type}}" placeholder="{{field.name}}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, `{{field.widget.input_type}}` returns the empty string here, though trying it from the shell it produces the `input_type`. So how can I access the input type of a field from the template?

I am not using `{{field}}` because I need to put a placeholder in each input field.

EDIT:

I just used `{{field}}` and a simple javascript, that place the placeholder in each input element field to be the same as the element name, though I still would like to know how to access `widget.input_type` from the template.

Comment: When you run the code that outputs the above have you tried looking at the output of the field.widget.input_type after the processing?

Comment: @Thingover yes, it just shows nothing, which means Django couldn't parse it, so just it fails "silently", as the docs would say :)

Comment: Try replacing field.widget.input_type with field.field.widget.input_type

Comment: `field.field.widget.input_type` did the trick for me, like @Tkingovr said

Answer (score 2):

Could I perhaps suggest and alternate means to get same thing?

Try putting

```py
attrs = {'placeholder':'your placeholder text here'}
```

into your form field widget like this:

```py
formfield = SomeField(widget = SomeWidget(attrs = {'placeholder':'your placeholder text here'} ))
```

Then you can just print out

```
{{ field }}
```

in template and be done with it.

Edit: In response to first comment.

Since i just started new project and downloaded html5 boilerplate with nice sleek loginform on top of the page i had to just do exactly what i suggested. I did it like that:

forms.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields['username'].label
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields['password'].label
```

Now perhaps your problem is that you want to also use django.contrib.auth.views.login for logging user in and that view uses django default authentication form. Not a problem!

open your urls.py and work this magic:

```py
from yourapp.forms import MyAuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$',
        login,
        {'template_name': 'yourapp/login.html', 'authentication_form':MyAuthenticationForm},
        name='auth_login'),
)
```

works like a charm

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the form field code source code, as it is the built in form of Django login. So it is a black box to me.

Comment: of course you have access to loginforms too. Import it extend it and replace its fields with your own fields of same type - just add placeholder text :)

Comment: But the built in django auth system use their login form, not mine :) and I don't want to build my auth system. anyway I found a work around , thanks a lot :)

Comment: you dont need to build your own auth system. thats what im showing in the examples. Look - the system uses both django default authentication form and view. But if you found another solution - just post it here. Perhaps someone else finds it useful too