# Accessing the Input Type from forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to access the Input Type to use in HTML but it appears to coming through as blank.

According to:
[Django: How to access form field input_type in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480342/django-how-to-access-form-field-input-type-in-a-template)

I should be using:

```
{{field.field.widget.input_type}}
```

But it seems to be returning blank.

CODE:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
      <input type="{{field.field.widget.input_type}}" class="form-control"
        name="{{ field.name }}"
        id="id_{{ field.name }}"
        value="{{ field.value }}" >
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier way to do that is by adding the HTML class to the field properties. You can do this by.

```
field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

In that whay, you would only need to do:

```
<label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
{{ field }}
```

edit: models -> forms

Comment: Hey Jinchuika, 

Thanks for this! One small edit I had to make: `field = *forms*.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))`. After this change, the suggested fix worked, so thanks a lot!